# How long does it take to do RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in the unfortunate situation of having to do a database restoration.

My full backup was at 9.30pm (157MB) and there were incrmentatl backups at 11am and 3pm.  The incremental backups are less than 30kb each.  It is now 6pm.

When I restored the full backup WITH RECOVERY, it took less than a minute.  But I could not apply the two transaction logs.

When I restored the full backup WITH NORECOVERY, it also took less than a minute to say it was successful, but then the database remained in the Restoring... state.  It has been like that for the last 40 minutes.  Task Manager shows almost no activity.  Is this normal?  Should I abort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it also took less than a minute to say it was successful, but then the database remained in the Restoring... state

It surely did, you're now supposed to restore an arbitrary number of transaction logs, all `WITH NORECOVERY`, and the last one `WITH RECOVERY`.

See [Understanding How Restore and Recovery of Backups Work in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Restoring full and differential database backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#restoring_full_n_differential_db_backups).

Comment: Thank you thank you!  Didn't realize Restoring... means I can apply the logs.  Read that MSDN link earlier and this point wasn't mentioned.